# How to style a TextButton?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT `TextButton`. The following css styles applied to the global css file do nothing:

```
.gwt-TextButton {
   color: red !important;
}
```

Why? What are the correct styles to be applied to change the style of all TextButton widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextButton` is a cell-backed widget and is based on the [appearance](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CellBackedWIdgets) pattern. It uses a `TextButtonCell` to render the content and wraps it using `CellWidget<T>`.

The global css you are looking for is `gwt-ButtonCellBase` but it is obfuscated because is used in a `ClientBundle`, so you need to extend `ButtonCellBase.DefaultAppearance.Resources`, providing your own `Style`. Much like any other cell-based widget. Then you need to use the right constructor (`TextButton(Appearance appearance, String text)`). Sample code follows.

Define the resource appearance extension (fully quoted for clarity):

```
public interface MyResources extends ButtonCellBase.DefaultAppearance.Resources {
  @Override
  @Source(value = {ButtonCellBase.DefaultAppearance.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "custom.css"})
  ButtonCellBase.DefaultAppearance.Style buttonCellBaseStyle();
}
```

Inside `custom.css`, override whatever you want of [`ButtonCellBase.css`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCellBase.css), and then inject everything:

```
MyResources customResources = GWT.create(MyResources.class);
TextButtonCell.Appearance customAppearance = new TextButtonCell.DefaultAppearance(customResources);
TextButton button = new TextButton(customAppearance, "Text");
```

You can very well do all the above just once, and always instantiate any new `TextButton` with the same appearance.

Comment: I can only use Appearance constructor with (SafeHtmlRenderer, Resource). Where can I get this SafeRenderer? I don't want to supply my own. I'm just trying to provide my own CSS styles. Why does this have to be done so complicated?

Comment: @membersound Added sample code. I know is not so straightforward.

Comment: This should be in the official docs, it's very comprehensible!